# Should I tell the interviewer that I have a holiday booked in a few months?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I will be leaving my temporary position soon at my current company will be starting to apply elsewhere. I'm in a weird spot where I have a ski holiday to Japan already planned and booked for January next year. My question is should this be something I mention in an interview?

I feel like it some companies may not hire me knowing they will lose me for 3 weeks in a few months, yet at the same time, it seems disingenuous not to mention it and would be a negative mark against me if I did get the job and told them later.

Thanks.

Comment: You think take a job and be denied a break or dismissed would be better?

Comment: Suppose you got a job without discussing the planned vacation, requested the time off, and your manager refused to allow it. Would you be willing to give up the vacation plan?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan If I went the "dont tell them" route, I would begrudgingly cancel the trip if they didnt let me have the time off, yes.

Comment: I would cancel the holiday. Seems a rather long holiday anyway

Comment: Be careful about "begrudgingly". Try for "graciously".

Answer (score 7):

You probably shouldn't bring it up in the interview itself; but you do need to be front and center about it if you're given an offer.  You haven't specified where you live but the biggest potential issue I see if you're in the US is that, especially for a new hire, many companies won't give 3 weeks of vacation total.

Comment: I live in Australia. It would have to be unpaid leave as I wouldnt have accumulated enough vacation hours by the time it comes around.

Comment: @Loocid I'm Australian as well, and I've seen some companies that are ok with a planned leave for new employees as long as it's quite clear that you intend to take it as unpaid leave.  Having said that, I would not bring it up in the interview but rather if you get an offer, raise it at that point.  The organisation can then make an informed decision as to whether their schedules can lose you for that period.  But again, that depends on the organisation.

Comment: @DanNeely Japan's timezone is close to Australia so jetlag shouldn't be an issue here. Good point though :)

Comment: +1, and as another Australian, definitely agree with Dan's answer and Jane's agreement. This is part of the discussions when an offer is made, part of the negotiation process of finding out if an agreement can be reached which works for both employer and employee.

Comment: Tend to agree that this is part of the answer to "when could you start".